# How do i style label tag on clicking the checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an html markup like this.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="Randomly generated ID" onclick="fun()">
<label for="CHECKBOX_ID" id="Randomly generated ID">SOME TEXT</label>
</body>
</html>
```

On clicking the checkbox i want to add a css style to label tag using fun() function in javascript.
I am having trouble in doing so, plus both the elements have a randomly generated ID and cannot have same ID's.

Comment: is it possible in your case to use CSS instead of JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the implementation using [Vanilla Js](http://vanilla-js.com/).

```js
function fun(inputElement) {
  var backgroundColor = inputElement.checked ? 'yellow' : 'white';
  var labelSelector = 'label[for="' + inputElement.id + '"]';
  var labelElement = document.querySelector(labelSelector);
  inputElement.style.background = backgroundColor;
  labelElement.style.background = backgroundColor;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="CHECKBOX_ID" onclick="fun(this)">
  <label for="CHECKBOX_ID" id="Randomly generated ID">SOME TEXT</label>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this will help you, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the specific clicked input element and apply css style on it

Here's a simple example using jQuery:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('fun-class');
});
```